# Typescript get param a by param b in an union type

Tags: typescript

I have two requests type `AddInterestAreaRequest` and `RemoveInterestAreaRequest`. And I want to make a util type that I can pass in the `action` and it returns me the `params`.

Here's what I have

```
type AddInterestAreaRequest = {
  action: 'addInterestArea';
  params: AddInterestAreaParams;
};

type RemoveInterestAreaRequest = {
  action: 'removeInterestArea';
  params: RemoveInterestAreaParams;
};

export type JSBRequest = {
  configs?: BridgeRequestConfigs;
} & (AddInterestAreaRequest | RemoveInterestAreaRequest);

type GetParamByAction<T extends JSBRequest['action']> =
  JSBRequest['action'] extends T ? never : JSBRequest['params'];

type Testing = GetParamByAction<'addInterestArea'>;
```

What I have is not working, `Testing` is `AddInterestAreaParams | RemoveInterestAreaParams` because `JSBRequest['params']` is always `AddInterestAreaParams | RemoveInterestAreaParams`

And I basically want to `Testing` to be only the `AddInterestAreaParams`

Any idea how I can achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can discriminate a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) at the type level by using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), which filters a union type `T` and keeps only those members assignable to `U`:

```
type GetParamByAction<T extends JSBRequest['action']> =
    Extract<JSBRequest, { action: T }>["params"]
```

So `Extract<JSBRequest, {action: T}>` will return only those members of `JSBRequest` whose `action` property is assignable to `T`, which should be just the one you want.  Then we [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into it to get its `params` property.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type Testing = GetParamByAction<'addInterestArea'>;
// type Testing = AddInterestAreaParams
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0ElzQgZzFSgjgAU4o4BbfZAbwFgAoZN5GAe04C5lCooAOYBuFgF8WLUJFiIUAJQjVOANwg5ZBIiXKUadJq3YAjSnwHCxzSc2m45SZACFB6IRCUBHAK7aAwpwgMMBChizsyGYAXhZggiCiElLMYACeAA4oGNgO2sSk3n6EyAC8DBHsiGDAQXwA5HCYmniEBXD11pEZ+rR8OS0kbboUVLTW4tYs6VnISirqg-m6RdplFcZs1bUgDSQLGnnDpJ2VbD1j+Hzzaodax3qXE1PMEAAeGZxQYMgzKABSAGVnKsSuUjJEEEEQmEAPx8VzAdyeCC+ALQ0L4CbIABkyAAFAMjjpCqjij8AD5zZS3JYPUFgACULz+yAA4hAwKMaM40qgEDUggAeAAqyHekBA6DoQJBZO0AG1GgKdvUALoAPjKZ2QAFE3vFqkLZQyADQMZDbOrIMXiDUKgBEFwMDrVKVZIu0wnWHK5vV5-MFICFjWaxPa9Q11gA9NHfpkUJ7CN7ykT7iTHgYgA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type GetParamByAction<T extends JSBRequest['action']> =
  T extends 'addInterestArea' ? AddInterestAreaRequest['params'] : RemoveInterestAreaRequest['params'];

type Testing = GetParamByAction<'addInterestArea'>;  // Should be AddInterestAreaParams
```

Comment: I might have 100 request types and so this is not gonna work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd suggest using the TS helper Extract to pull the type from the union first:

```js
type GetJSBRequestByAction<T extends JSBRequest['action']> = Extract<JSBRequest, { action: T }>;


type Test1 = GetJSBRequestByAction<'addInterestArea'>;

// This gives:
// {
//    configs?: BridgeRequestConfigs;
// } & AddInterestAreaRequest
```

And then you can just access the parameters:

```
type GetParamByAction<T extends JSBRequest['action']> = GetJSBRequestByAction<T>['params'];
```

Comment: Thanks. This works and is exactly what I'm looking for. The answer below is a bit more informative. So I'm accepting that one, sorry.